# SVN LOG and SVN Diff

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I'm really new coding in ava
These are my commands that I want to write using SVNKIT

```
svn log -v -rRevision URLString
```

and also

```
svn diff --summarize -rRevisionStart:Revisionend URLLINK
```

I know that i should use SVNKIT but I have difficulty using it. 
Can anybody help me with writing it?

Thanks